# Testing IIFE with setTimeout

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, sinon

What is the best way to test IIFE (Immediately Invoked Function Expression) that calls itself recursively with `setTimeout`:

```
(function myFuncToBeTested() {
  // Code to be tested 
  ...
  setTimeout(myFuncToBeTested, timeout) // timeout should be checked
})()
```

I found the following solution that replaces global `setTimeout` function with `own` stub. This has following issues:

```
// Saving original setTimeout. This should be restored in test cleanup
originalSetTimeout = global.setTimeout

// Replace  with function
global.setTimeout = function setImmediate(myFunc, interval) {
   // FIXME: This function now always called

   // Save interval to be tested
   savedInterval = interval
}
```

Comment: Are you able to spy on the contents of `myFuncToBeTested`? Does it have any side effects? What do you intend to assert in your tests?

Comment: >Are you able to spy on the contents of `myFuncToBeTested`

- actually not

Comment: As I mentioned I should "stub" `setTimeout` execution and simply test if `setTimeout` has been called and its `interval`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I want to suggest a hybrid solution between thedarklord47's answer and your experiments with stubbing `setTimeout`. An IIFE like you have is inherently difficult to test, since you left no approach by which to check if it has been called. You can modify your API as follows:

```
var repeater = {
  start: function () {
    this.func();

    setTimeout(this.start.bind(this), timeout);
  },
  func: function () {
    // code to be tested
  }
};
```

Then your test can look something like this (since you tagged with [sinon](/questions/tagged/sinon) I have used it, and in particular its fake timer API which will allow you to check your interval functionality):

```
// setup
var clock = sinon.useFakeTimers();
var spy = sinon.spy(repeater, 'func');

// test
repeater.start();
assert(spy.calledOnce);

// advance clock to trigger timeout
clock.tick(timeout);
assert(spy.calledTwice);

// advance clock again
clock.tick(timeout);
assert(spy.calledThrice);

// teardown
clock.restore();
spy.restore();
```

Answer (score 3):

could this function be made into an object?

```
var myObject = (function(){

    function start(){
        myFuncToBeTested();       
        setTimeout(start, 10);
        return this;
    }

    function myFunctToBeTested(){
        //Code to be tested
    }

    return {
        start: start,
        myFuncToBeTested: myFuncToBeTested
    }
})().start();
```

and then you could use testing framework of your choice to test:

```
assert( myObject.myFuncToBeTested() == expectedValue );
```

Comment: I think you should either make `start()` return `this`, or call `myObject.start()` in a separate statement. As-is, `myObject` will be `undefined` in your code snippet.